# Jsoup, remove Elements from Elements

Tags: java, jsoup, element

So I got several Elements captured and I want to remove these out of another captured Elements.

My Code looks like this:

```
   try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FullFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    Elements remove = doc.select("cssquerytofindremoveElements");
```

I now got my Elements which I want to remove, let's say I got antoher

```
Elements el = doc.select("cssquery");
```

I want to remove the Elements I selected before ("remove") from the Elements I selected just now ("el").

Big thanks to everyone helping :)

Comment: Can you complete your post with the html code you fetch and the css queries you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

There you go, boom!

```
el.select("cssquerytofindremoveElements").remove();
```

Comment: Well ... it's not working though :( I got everything done as you said and tried it exactly the same ...

Comment: Ok my fault, it should be working now, but it still doesn't work. I tried this: `Elements el = spieltagElements.select("td.Heim[colspan=2]").remove();` where as "spieltagElements" are my selected Elements, but if I print out my "el" i'll only find the Elements I wanted to remove. @Joel Min